# Display First DIV beneath Second DIV

Tags: html, css

say I have...

```
<div id="A"></div>
<div id="B"></div>
```

How can the end-user view div B on top of div A on their browser?

I'm trying to do this with CSS without editing the html.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `flex-box` and `order` to acheive what you want

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

#A {
  width: 100%;
  height:50px;
  background: red;
  color:white;
  order: 2;
}

#B {
  width: 100%;
  height:50px;
  background: black;
  color:white;
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="A">A</div>
<div id="B">B</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `display:flex;` and `flex-direction:column-reverse;` to the parent of your two divs.

```
body{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column-reverse;
}
```

Or you can choose div's order manually with `order` property:

```
body {
  display: flex;
}

#A {
  order: 2;
}

#B {
  order: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `CSS3 flex` to change the positioning of flex elements and this can be done using `order property`,

> The CSS order property specifies the order used to lay out flex items
>   in their flex container.

```css
#box{
 display:flex;
 width:100%;
 flex-direction:column;
}
.A{
 order:2;
  background:#111;
  color:#fff;
}
.B{
 order:1;
  background:#111;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
<div class="A">A</div>
<div class="B">B</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

A way to do this in CSS:

The container must have `display:flex` attribute

Then :

```
#A{
   order:2;
}

#B{
   order:1;
}
```

You can also achieve this with jQuery

```
$('#B:parent').each(function () {
    $(this).insertBefore($(this).prev('#A'));
});
```

Answer (score -1):

It feels unclean to do it this way but here you go (no container element needed)

```css
#A {
  display: table-footer-group;
}

#B {
  display: table-header-group;
}
```

```html
<div id="A">A</div>
<div id="B">B</div>
```

Comment: @BaptisteArnaud um, what?